# Use of two tos together

Tags: prepositions, grammaticality, redundancy

Is this sentence correct?

> The culling of poultry has been resorted to to save humans.

Can someone give me more examples where two *to*s are used together?

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/198917/are-there-other-acceptable-juxtapositions-of-polysemes

Comment: Yes, it's fine, although some people consider trailing prepositions and passive voice poor style. That said, 'to save humans' doesn't feel natural - maybe 'to save human lives'? If you wanted to separate the two 'to's you could make the second one 'in order to', e.g. 'has been resorted to in order to save human lives'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The game that we went to to see my son play in was canceled.

The person you snuggled up to to keep warm last night said don't ever do that again.

I gave him a good talking to to get my point across.

The dance instructor you got close to to talk to tore his tutu too.